# Water trapped behind shower caulk?

Tags: shower, mold, caulking

After removing moldy caulk in a shower it seems that water was trapped behind the caulk. Here's a picture of the base of the door frame which shows the likely entry points for water behind the caulk.
[image: door frame]

I imagine water is entering through the rectangular openings in the door frame. While I could probably get rid of the water trapped now I imagine it will be quickly replaced. Should I plan on replacing caulk annually, or is there any way to prevent or retard the growth of mold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caulk the outside, leave the inside open so it can drain back to the tub/shower. Or at least leave gaps in the inside caulking for drainage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It eventually passed the most difficult test - I convinced my wife that you answer made sense!